# Properly using separate tabs with Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, c

I'm trying to split up a large project of mine into separate tabs in the Arduino IDE and I'm having more than a few troubles with it. My main trouble is finding a way to have routines in extra tabs access the Serial object; because it's really hard to debug things with `Serial.println()` otherwise. All I get, though, is "'Serial' was not declared in this scope".
There appears to be some kind of trick to this? I've noticed that "byte" or "bool" needs to be declared in .cpp tabs and .h tabs but not on the main one?
Is there some kind of easy way to set this up so that I don't need to constantly `#include <stdbool.h>` and `typedef unsigned char byte;`?

Current issue: Main file:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(500000);
  PrintMessage();
}

void loop() {
}
```

driver.ino file:

```
byte PrintMessge () {
  Serial.println("printin");
}
```

and on compiling:

```
error: 'PrintMessage' was not declared in this scope
```

EDIT: Found a silly typo. Problem solved.

Comment: Did you try `#include <Arduino.h>` at the beginning? That should expose the `Serial` object. Otherwise you'll need to show us the code files in which the error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is more about C/C++ header basics rather than Arduino. Anyways, you should have the following file structure: Code in `.cpp`files, Header in `.h` files. Main sketch either `.ino` or `.cpp` (for cpp remember that you must explicitly write out the function prototypes!)

So for your small example that would be:

`main.ino`:

```
#include "driver.h"
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(500000);
  PrintMessage();
}

void loop() {
}
```

`driver.cpp`

```
#include "driver.h"
byte PrintMessage () {
  Serial.println("printin");
  return 0; //previously had no return although returning 'byte'.
}
```

`driver.h`

```
 //Always use include guards
 #ifndef DRIVER_H
 #define DRIVER_H

 #include <Arduino.h>
 //All function prototypes from driver.cpp.
 byte PrintMessage();

 #endif /* DRIVER_H */
```

Also corrected a typo from `PrintMessge` to `PrintMessage`. This is the "professional" way to do it, seperate implementation and header files.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs are actually quite simple:

- If it's named `<something>.ino` it will get merged with the main tab. It's just like working in one big file and you don't need to do anything special.
- If it's named `<something>.cpp` or `<something>.c` it's a completely separate *translation unit* and has to be manually "enroled" into the Arduino system by including the `Arduino.h` header.

So it's simplest to just name them as INO files not CPP files and you don't have to do anything special:

[image][image]

Comment: That's not working out for me for some reason. I'm getting the compilation error `No such file or directory` at the line `#include "drtiver.ino"`

Comment: Why are you trying to include an ino file???

Comment: Because if I don't then I get errors that make less sense. Main file:
`void setup() {
  Serial.begin(500000);
  PrintMessage();
}`

driver.ino file: 

`byte ReadMessge () {
  Serial.println("printin");
}` Error 'PrintMessage' not declared in this scope.

Comment: Um... yes? You'd expect that when you have one calling `PrintMessage` and the other providing `ReadMessage`...

Comment: Typo. They're both PrintMessage(). Will edit comment as soon as it lets me.

Comment: See the images I posted in my answer. That works. If it's not working for you then you have done something else wrong. You will have to post more details in your question.

Comment: Main question edited.

Comment: You can't spell *Message*...

Comment: I'll assume that was a typo too...